# Google query date column sort issue

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

When I use

```
=query('Sheet1'!B2:E, "select B,C,D,E Order By B DESC",-1 )
```

where D is a date column the query works. But it does not work when I try to sort "B ASC" , Why?

Answer (score 2):

it works too but your output is at the end of spreadsheet (scroll all the way down). to "fix" this you can do:

```
=QUERY('Sheet1'!B2:E, "select B,C,D,E where B is not null order By B asc", -1)
```